# Wording in English for "quantité conjuguée" in French

Tags: terminology

In French when you have an expression of the type $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}$, the expression $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$ is named the "quantité conjuguée". This is useful when you want to bound
$$\vert \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y} \vert = \frac{\vert x-y \vert}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} }$$

What is the equivalent wording in English?

By the way second question... when I use the word "expression" above, is it appropriate? Would "quantity" be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, it is also termed the "[conjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_%28algebra%29)." The conjugate of $a+b$ is $a-b$.

As for your second question, "[expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_%28mathematics%29)" is better (in the sense that it has a firmer meaning), though "[quantity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantity#Quantity_in_mathematics)" also works.

Comment: Easy... thanks Peter. And is "expression" appropriate to refer to something like $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}$

Comment: @Jean-PierreMerx I have just updated my answer :)

Comment: It makes no sense *in general* to say that $\,a-b\,$ is the conjugate of $\,a+b\,$ (else e.g. $\,0=0+0\,$ has conjugate $\,0-0\,$ contra $\,0 = 1-1\,$ has conjugate $\,1+1).\,$ Conjugation is well-defined only in specific contexts (as in the OP, the conjugation automorphism of a quadratic field).

Comment: I think it makes sense for the conjugation of "$a-b$" to be "$a+b$," but only if we keep it in the form of just exchanging plus/minus between two quantities.